# After adding PPA source for "skippy-xd", the package still cannot be found

Tags: apt, lubuntu, ppa

After adding PPA source for "skippy-xd", the package still can not be found:

```
majo@think:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:landronimirc/skippy-xd
[sudo] password for majo:
You are about to add the following PPA to your system:
  Fullscreen composited task-switcher for X11
 Skippy-XD is a program that provides Exposé-like features found on the Mac
 OS X operating system. It is a standalone application for providing a window 
 picker with live previews (including live video) on Linux desktops that run 
 an X server with compositing support. Thus it is not part of the window
 manager, and the compositing is not being used all the time. 

 If you work with many windows, your desktop may begin to get cluttered.  You 
 can use Skippy-XD to quickly and conveniently find the right window that you
 are looking for. It allows you to press a hotkey and see miniature versions 
 of all your active windows at once.

 To use Skippy-XD, you need Xfce (xfwm4) or a NetWM compliant window
 manager (LXDE, Openbox-based window managers, etc.).

 http://code.google.com/p/skippy-xd/
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~landronimirc/+archive/skippy-xd
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmp1q3041/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmp1q3041/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key 23A187B2 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmp1q3041/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 23A187B2: public key "Launchpad PPA for Landronimirc" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
majo@think:~$ sudo apt-get update
...
Reading package lists... Done
majo@think:~$ sudo apt-get install skippy-xd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package skippy-xd
majo@think:~$ apt-cache search skippy
majo@think:~$ apt-cache search skippy-xd
```

I am using ubuntu 13.04 with lubuntu-desktop additionally installed on my laptop. I get the same result on my netbook, where I have clean lubuntu 13.04 installed.
Downloading the package manually and installing works just fine, though. So it is not a big deal. But I was just wondering why I could not get the PPA working right. Thanks in advance for any advices.

Answer (score 4):

LATEST EDIT: Short answer is: `skippy-xd` lacks a `Build-Depends:` dependency on the `python` package. That's why the PPA's automatic build fails and no package ends up being in the repository.

---

According to the [PPA page](https://launchpad.net/~landronimirc/+archive/skippy-xd/+packages) the builds for raring amd64 and i386 failed february this year. Maybe you want to get in touch with the PPA owner or build the package yourself and see if you can fix it. You should be able to `apt-get source skippy-xd` and `apt-get build-dep skippy-xd` since the source packages are available through that PPA.

EDIT: Double checked, there are no binary packages for Raring inside that PPA. Quick hint on how to build yourself:

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
$ sudo apt-get build-dep skippy-xd
$ apt-get source skippy-xd
$ cd skippy-xd-0.5.1~hg20111223
$ dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -rfakeroot
```

Be prepared to see some mess. After all it did not compile on Launchpad compile farm and the PPA owner chose not to care about it.

EDIT2:

I just compiled it successfully on Linux Mint 15 (based on Ubuntu Raring) i386. Checking the [build log](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/130660315/buildlog_ubuntu-raring-amd64.skippy-xd_0.5.1~hg20111223-1~raring~ppa5_FAILEDTOBUILD.txt.gz) on launchpad says:

```
dh build-arch 
   dh_testdir -a
   dh_auto_configure -a
   dh_auto_build -a
make[1]: Entering directory `/build/buildd/skippy-xd-0.5.1~hg20111223'
python configure_environment_header.py
make[1]: python: Command not found
make[1]: *** [environment.h] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory `/build/buildd/skippy-xd-0.5.1~hg20111223'
dh_auto_build: make -j1 returned exit code 2
make: *** [build-arch] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build-arch gave error exit status 2
******************************************************************************
Build finished at 20130207-2027
FAILED [dpkg-buildpackage died]
******************************************************************************
```

It seems to me a mandatory `Build-Dep` is missing, which is a common error when the `Build-Dep` in question is available on the developers machine (python). That's one reason why there are build servers. Sadly the PPA owner did not care to check the build results.

CONCLUSION after the latest EDIT:

Build yourself and install the package by double clicking it with your favorite file browser. Create a bug ticket or contact PPA owner about this issue.

Have fun!!

Comment: Another two tips: Include the Ubuntu version you use with your question, always. Consider to not use skippy from the PPA. The daddy doesn't have so much heart for his baby.

Comment: I just see that you did include the version, and that you already installed manually. My reading skills are not up to speed sometimes. ;)

Comment: The build dependency that needs is `python-dev` which will complete the build.

Comment: I think it is just `python`, not the `-dev` package.

Comment: Weird, it install `Setting up python2.7 (2.7.3-15ubuntu2) ...` through.

Comment: You mean `skyppy-xd` `Depends:` on `python` I suppose? I mean that this package lacks a `Build-Depends:`, that's why it builds on my machine (`python` installed, but not `python-dev`) and also why it fails on launchpad, because `build-essential` does not `Depends:` on `python`. That is a packaging bug.

Comment: And everything comes down to a bad maintainer... :(

Comment: @JoBo i just sent an email to the guy, the 'python' program doesn't exist in the build environment for that package, he might be pulling in python2.7 which might be a different executable name than the standard 'python' package, in which case he'll need to change his build scripts to account for the different python executable names...

Comment: @thomas-w Really, it is `python` [or: `python-minimal`] that is missing as `Build-Depends:`, literally. It is not in the build environment, because it is not in the package`s control file. `python2.7` or whatever doesn't matter... it's all been taken care of by the dependencies. Just declare `python` or `python-minimal` and the `buildd` will create the build environment properly. That's its job, just as it is its job to fail the build, if the packaging is not straight.

Comment: @JoBo i understand that, however it *is* possible to use `python2.7` as the build program if it's absolutely needed.  The point is that they still need to fix it, and I sent them an email about it.  That's all.

Comment: I think you still did not get it. `python2.7` is actually installed during build, still it fails! Have a look at the build log linked in my answer. The missing link  `/usr/bin/python => /usr/bin/python2.7` is provided by `python-minimal` (pun intended). `python` depends on `python-minimal` depends on `python2.7-minimal`. See? It is not about 2.7, just add `Build-Depends: python-minimal` and you're fine. (Or `Build-Depends: python`, like I wrote days ago.)

Comment: I checked with the PPA maintainer.  They pushed the Raring package and the PPA works as expected now, according to the maintainer of the PPA.

Comment: @Thomas W. I added a separate answer addressing the PPA build issues.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the `ppa:landronimirc/skippy-xd`; even if all the builds were fixed, it is obsolete.

Use instead [ppa:landronimirc/skippy-xd-daily](https://launchpad.net/~landronimirc/+archive/skippy-xd-daily), which provides daily builds of most recent [development code](https://github.com/richardgv/skippy-xd) of `Skippy-XD`. All the builds should be available as expected.